# import CSV to Neo4j on MAC OS

Tags: macos, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j, just wondering how I should address my CSV file to import to the Neo4j on MAC OS?

I have tried this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://macintosh hd/desktop/alarm.csv" AS csvLine
```

Regards

Comment: Hi @KouPa, let me know if my answer helped to solve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ Bruno, Thanks and sorry for my delay to reply. I have received this error after that: Query cannot conclude with LOAD CSV (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 58 (offset: 57))
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///alarm.csv" AS csvLine"

Comment: You are welcome. You are getting this error because a Cypher command cannot end with a `LOAD CSV` statement. Probably you want to do something with each line, like create a node. Something like `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///alarm.csv" AS csvLine WITH csvLine CREATE (:Node {id : csvLine.id, name : csvLine.name})`, considering you have `name` and `id` columns in your CSV line.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your file inside Neo4j's import directory. According to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations) the import directory for macOS systems is `${HOME}/Documents/Neo4j/import`.

1. Copy the file `alarm.csv` to `${HOME}/Documents/Neo4j/import`.
2. Load the CSV file running `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///alarm.csv" AS csvLine`